# sort search result by year dropdown codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to search the result by year. i get undefined variable:q . where is the problem?

this is my view

```
<?php echo form_open("announcement/year");?>
<?php echo form_label('Year','q');?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('q', $q, set_value('q'), 'id="q"'); ?>
<?php echo form_close();
```

this is my controller

```
if ($q == '') $q = $this->input->post('q');
    $this->data['q'] = $q;
if ($q == '') redirect($this->announcement);

$this->data['data'] = $this->ann_model->get_year
```

this is my model

```
function get_list_search($q)

{$result1 = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Announcement
    WHERE Date LIKE '%$q%' 
    ORDER BY ID DESC";

    ........}
```

please help me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change this

```
$this->data['data'] = $this->ann_model->get_year
```

to

```
$this->data['data'] = $this->ann_model->get_list_search($q);
```

And in model return the query result.

Comment: I will try first.. :)